# CMake's find_package(OpenMP) cannot find OpenMP when using clang-12

Tags: cmake, clang, openmp

I'm currently trying to find OpenMP using `cmake`.

Below is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(GCC_COMPILE_FLAGS -Wall -Werror -Wvla -O0)

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

# Find OpenMP
find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have `libomp-dev` installed as shown below:

```
libomp-dev is already the newest version (1:10.0-50~exp1).
```

When I set `gcc` as my compiler, `cmake` has no issues finding OpenMP.

However, when I use `clang-12` as my compiler by specifying the following `cmake` flags:

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang-12 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++-12
```

I get the following "cannot find OpenMP error" from `cmake`:

```
CMake Error at cmake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP_C
```

How should I set up my `CMakeLists.txt` file so that OpenMP can be found when using `clang` as my compiler?

Comment: According to the list of files provided by [libomp-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libomp-10-dev/filelist) package, it provides OpenMP support for clang-10. OpenMP support for `clang-12` should come with clang-12 itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev pointed out, since I had `libomp-dev` version `10` installed, `CMake` would be able to find OpenMP if I used `clang-10`.

So in order for me to use OpenMP with `clang-12`, I had to make sure that `libomp-dev` version 12 was installed, which I did using the following shell command:

```
sudo apt -y install libomp-12-dev
```

Now CMake has no issues finding OpenMP when I use `clang-12` as my compiler.

Comment: indeed, it also solved my problem with clang-13! Yeay